# What type of poem is this

Tags: poetry, poetic

I'm no English major. And I'm no poet either.

But I love to read and I really like poetry.

Anyways I found this Poem, and I hadn't seen anything like it before.

*Sky. 
Clouds sailing the soft blue Ocean. 
 Endless waves break on the Sand. 
 Infinite expanse of tiny Diamonds. 
 Buried deep, handheld Stars. 
Specks of light that dot the Sky. 
 Clouds sailing the soft blue Ocean.*
*~Anonymous*

It seems to be a loop of definitions. where each line defines the last word of the line before.

Do any of you know what type of poem this is?

Comment: You should tell us the name of the poet, that is the least one could do here.

Comment: @lambie someone showed it to me a while ago. And they didn't say where they got it.

Comment: See also [writing.se] Good Luck.

Comment: It's looks like variation of a chain poem. Instead of using the last word in the line as the first word of the next line, the poet has explained the last word of each line. I'd called it a contiguity term. Dunno if it's an actual form. It does indeed form a loop or link, given that it ends up where it started. Maybe Japanese?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most broadly, this is an example of **[constrained writing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constrained_writing)**, where a poet imposes a particular constraint on their form and then follows the creative implications of that constraint. While in many established verseforms constraints are associated with rhyme, number of lines, meter, and other formal elements, constraints can also come from other linguistic or contextual features. For instance, an *[acrostic](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/learn/glossary-terms/acrostic)* involves fitting the first letter of each line to spell out something specific.

In this case, the constraint involves defining the last word of the line before it until the word for the initial line appears, at which point the initial line repeats. Beyond that, I have found no named *type* for this poem. This is not unusual - lots of nonce forms, defined by constraints created on particular occasions, exist.